# ColdFusion threads: looping session variables + sleep

Tags: multithreading, session, loops, coldfusion, timer

hey guys I'm trying to create a timer which counts the time spent on a page using a thread heres what I have so far:

```
<cfset session.time=0>
<cfthread name="timer" action="run">
<cfscript>
  counter = 0;
  while (counter <9000) {
    sleep(1000);
    session.time++;
    counter ++;
} 
</cfscript>
</cfthread>
```

page 2:

```
<cfoutput>#session.time#</cfoutput>
```

page 2 gives me 0 every time anyone see a problem?

edit:
I changed line 1 of my code to `<cfset session.time=100>` and now page 2 says 100, its like the stuff inside the cfscript loop isn't reassigning session.time

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. You have got an Application.cfm page setup to enable session management i.e:

```
<cfapplication name="#hash(getCurrentTemplatePath())#"  
    sessiontimeout="#createTimeSpan(0,0,20,0)#" sessionmanagement="true"/>
```

Comment: I believe this is enabled already, other session variables passed to other pages work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

Are you sure you are using the Developer or Enterprise edition of ColdFusion and the threads have actually kicked off? I think only those editions support multi-threading.

One way to do verity your threads working is to use `cfstat` - you should see one request running even though your page has returned.

Another is to write output from your spawned thread - use the code snipped below to write to System.out - ideally you'll need to have CF running as a console task to do this.

```
<cfset session.time=0 />

<cfthread name="timer" action="run">
<cfscript>
  counter = 0;
  while (counter <9000) {
    sleep(1000);
    session.time++;

    sys = createObject("java", "java.lang.System");
    sys.out.println("*** [DEBUG]  - #timeformat(now(),'HH:mm:ss' )# - session.time=#session.time# ");

    counter ++;
} 
</cfscript>
</cfthread>
```

Comment: Standard supports multithreading, but you are limited on background thread count (to 10, IIRC).

Answer (score -1):

**Code executed inside a thread has its own scope, including session.**  I would set a variable within the tread and then access it from within the threads scope.

i.e.
Change `session.time++;` to `thread.time++;` and then use `cfthread[timer].time` to get the thread's time.

Although this may not hold if you enable session management like some of the other posts discuss.

Comment: any idea on how to store the last cfthread[timer].time in a session variable so I can view it on page 2?

Comment: sorry I forgot to include the thread scope.  If you create and modify the variable as an entry of thread scope within a thread, it should be accessible from anywhere.  Use thread.time within the tread, and then on the second page try cfthread[threadName].variableName--no session scope required!

Comment: I just tried this, it doesn't see to recognize the variable on pg 2. I simplified it just to test it out. 
<cfthread name="timer" action="run">
<cfset Thread.time = 0>
</cfthread>

page 2: 
#cfthread[timer].time#

throws an   Variable TIMER is undefined.  error

Comment: Wrong - session scope is shared between threads. See http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=threads_4.html, specifically 'All the threads run in a request share the same Form, URL, Request, CGI, Cookie, Session, Application, Server and Client scopes.'

Comment: Ah yes, appologies I was mixing up my scopes with web requests, where the request executes within its own session scope.